# How to get Checkbox value from a public class which is not in the form

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a checkbox located in a form and I want to get its value from a public class not in the form. It should something like follows.

```
public class Employee
{
    // ...

    public string LookUpName(string doc)
    {
        if (checkbox1.checked == true)
        {
            return something;
        }
        else 
            return something;
    }
}
```

The problem in this way that the checkbox is not recognized in the class `LookUpName`. Any help please ? Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Decouple the Employee class from UI, and pass the value in as a parameter:

```
public string LookUpName(string doc, bool isSomething)
{
      if (isSomething)
      {
           return something;
      }

      return somethingElse;
}
```

Also, `checkbox1` is not a good name for a checkbox...

Comment: how to get the value of bool isSomething? is it from the checkbox ??

Answer (score 0):

It should go the other way around.  Your CheckBox should get its value from a property.  Then your class can react to that property.